# Sass constant refresh failure in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, preprocessor

I have been having problems refreshing compiled **sass** on my chrome when working on my `.scss`. I commonly work with stylus lang and I never have this problem.

Compiled sass is giving me a nightmare with Chrome, I don't know if it is something related to sass or chrome. But I wish to find a solution.

First, when I save changes on my `.scss` with the  `--watch` command, it generates the `.css` automatically, I see the last changes in the new CSS. Then I go to chrome and hit **f5** so I can see changes... and voila.... nothing... nothing happens =), it doesn't refresh at all, hit **f5** multiple times etc... but nothing. The only solution: close my browser and start anew.

I am using incognito chrome so I can close the incognito window and start a new one. But even that way, I am wasting a lot of time doing it, wish I wouldn't close the window anymore.

My terminal command is: `sass scss/style.scss:css/style.css --watch`

I even used: `sass scss/style.scss:css/style.css --watch --no-source-map`

Comment: Do you have a sass-cache folder in your project root?

Comment: Bit of a side note but you should have a look at using something like 'gulp.js' task automation if you haven't already. You can set up live browser reloading amongst other things. No more f5!

Comment: @paddyfields not gulp in this project, I had used gulp on other projects, but I think I will do it on this. By the way, I never used the live browser reloading, will search for it

Comment: @MattiaAstorino nop, I don't have a sass-cache forlder and never had, should I do it?